# iOS: Edit object inside a method

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to edit an object inside a method like this:

```
-(void) createSprite:(CatSprite*) sprite{
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:BASE_SPRITE_IMAGE];
CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
sprite =[CatSprite spriteWithCGImage:imageRef  key:nil];
```

}

and the call of the method like this:

```
[self createSprite:mySprite];
```

When debugging the method the object sprite is allocated, but after executing the method the object mySprite is null. Thank you.
PS: mySprite is an instance variable of type CatSprite (Extention from CCSprite).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'm assuming you're using ARC. Second, you have two ways of doing this, though I'd recommend the first option...

**Option 1**

Return a new sprite, instead of trying to modify the caller's pointer:

```
- (CatSprite *)createSprite{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:BASE_SPRITE_IMAGE];
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
    return [CatSprite spriteWithCGImage:imageRef key:nil];
}
```

You'd call this method using:

```
mySprite = [self createSprite];
```

**Option 2**

Pass a pointer to a pointer, and dereference:

```
- (void)createSpriteUsingSpritePointer:(CatSprite **)spritePointer{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:BASE_SPRITE_IMAGE];
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
    *spritePointer = [CatSprite spriteWithCGImage:imageRef  key:nil];
}
```

You'd call this method using:

```
[self createSprite:&mySprite];
```

Comment: Second way is beautiful!